# Getting Google Earth to work with Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, google-earth

Is it possible to have Google Earth integrated into a Silverlight app? I've tried searching on Google but the best results I could find were forum posts from 2008 which were uncertain at best.

Comment: I believe that Telerik has a map component that allows you to pull Google data, but I wouldn't call that Google Earth integration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is any straightforward way to utilize Google Earth from a Silverlight application.  And even if you could get it to work, you would have practically no control over the Google Earth portion of the program since, to my knowledge, it is not designed to be hosted in other applications.

However, if what you want is a 2D/3D GIS (Geographic Information System) inside your Silverlight application, an alternative to Google Earth is the Bing Maps Silverlight Control.  This is already Silverlight compatible, has a full 2D/3D API and provides some of the same features as Google Earth.

Here are two links about the Bing Maps Silverlight Control:

- [Bing Maps Silverlight Control 1.0 Released](http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2009/11/09/bing-maps-silverlight-control-1-0-released.aspx)
- [Changes to Bird’s eye and 3D Maps](http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2010/11/02/changes-to-bird-s-eye-and-3d-maps.aspx)

As I recall, you have to apply for a free license to use this and there are some restrictions.  Please read the license carefully.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the following links:

- [Using Google Maps with ArcGIS Silverlight](http://rexdotnet.blogspot.com/2010/09/use-google-maps-with-arcgis-silverlight.html)
- [Display Google Maps Imagery using Bing Maps Silverlight Control](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2010/06/14/Display_Google_Maps_Imagery_using_Bing_Maps_Silverlight_Control.aspx)

However, there do exists some legal issues as Google has prohibit the use of Google Map outside of their supplied API. As pointed in the first link:

> Now for the legal answer. In short, no. You cannot access Google Maps imagery outside of an interface (read: APIs) provided by Google.